# Does there exist non-trivial linear functional on $(C[0,1], ||\cdot||_2)$ which doesn't come from the inner product on $L^2[0,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X=C[0,1]$ i.e. the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with $L^2$ norm. Then there exists an $F\in X^*$ i.e. dual of $X$ such that there exists no $g \in X$ so that 
$$ F(f) = \langle f,g \rangle$$ holds for all $f \in X$.

My effort: Since $(X,|| \cdot ||_{2})$ is not complete. Hence it is not a Hailbert space. We can't apply the Riesz Representation Theorem.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $F:C[0,1]$ be a continuous linear functional. $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$. You can verify that continuous linear maps into complete spaces with domain being a dense subspaces extend _uniquely_ to continuous linear maps on the entire space. This means that $F$ is the resctriction of a linear functional on $L^2[0,1]$, here Riesz tells you that $F$ is the same as $F(g)=\int \bar f g$ for some $f\in L^2[0,1]$, not necessarily in $C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $F(f) = \int_0^{1 \over 2} f - \int_{1 \over 2}^1 f$. The operator
$F$ is linear & continuous.

The (an) obvious candidate is $g = 1_{[0,{1 \over 2})} - 1_{({1 \over 2},1]}$, but it is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $h(x) = x^{-1/4}.$ Consider the $F\in X^*$ given by $F(f) = \langle f,h\rangle.$